# Nginx any uri to root directory

Tags: nginx

How can I make any request to Nginx server be served from fixed static page ("/html/index.html")?

For example: I want following requests to be served from /html/index.html
    localhost/ 
    localhost/data
    localhost/data/html
    localhost/data/images

Nginx by default appending the URI to my root directory and is looking for it in local file system.

Comment: [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root /html;

location / {
  try_files /index.html =404;
}
```